# Initialise Formik with default values depending on user actions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fullcalendar, react-bootstrap, formik

I'm trying to initialise a Formik form with default values depending on the date that the user click on a calendar.

Should be easy to do, but my lack of experience on ReactJS and Formik don't allow me find the solution.

I've tried different ways in the last days without success.

I will appreciate a little of help about this issue. Thank you.

Below I attach a diagram about the project for to understand better that I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance!

[image: ReactJS project diagram]

Comment: when user click on date and select it you can access it on your values and think that when we have values.date for example i want to open a modal, if you need more example comment and tag me

Comment: Hi @sinafarhadi I don't understand very well what you mean. Could you give me more details please. Thanks for your response.

Comment: do you want to write a answer for you @Sknkronice ?

Comment: @sinafarhadi yes, I want please. If you know the solution and you have time for to help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

in the formik we have an option to access values and do somethings on it

 
**Validate Field**

Look At The Below Code
its Formik Component

```
<Formik

     initialValues={{
        date: '',
     }}

     // Validating Data
     validate={values => {

     const errors = {};

      if (!values.date) {
        errors.date = 'Date Is Required';
      }
      if (values.date) {
        // We Have Date Now and User Selects it
        alert('Hello')
      }

      return errors;
     }}

     // Submit Action
     onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        alert('form submitted')
        setSubmitting(false);
     }}
     >
     {({
      values,
      handleChange,
      errors,
      handleSubmit,
      setFieldValue
     }) => (

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
             <div>
                 <DatePicker
                     selected={values.date}
                     onChange={(time)=> setFieldValue("date", time)}
                     placeholderText={"Choose Time"}
                     showTimeSelect
                     timeFormat="HH:mm"
                     timeIntervals={15}
                     dateFormat="LLL"
                     timeCaption="Time"
                  />
              </div>
         <form />
     )}
    </Formik>
```

> The Validate Option Can Handle You Question

Comment: Try This Method... Its Should Work For You

Comment: thanks for your response, but your solution don't help me in this case

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've resolved the issue storing in the state of my **Modal** component the property **initialValues** that **Formik** use for to initialise the fields.

So when the **EventEmitter** fire an event the listener will receive the custom data from the calendar and I will initialise the **Formik** form with its default values.